# Calling one non thread-safe method in a thread from another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

Suppose I have a non thread-safe Class X on the main thread and I have another class Y which is in another thread and needs to call a method doX() of Class X.
I would simply pass a reference of Class X to Class Y and call doX() from Y however this class X is non thread-safe and if called from another thread behaves weirdly.

How can I let Y call method doX() of X from X's thread? in the SSCC below the managedthreadid should always be the same (but it isn't).

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ThreadApp
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            int managedThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Main ManagedThreadId = " + managedThreadId);

            X x = new X();
            x.doX();

            Y y = new Y();
            y.fun(x);
        }
    }

    class X
    {
        public void doX()
        {
            int managedThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("X ManagedThreadId = " + managedThreadId);
        }
    }

    class Y
    {
        public void fun(X x)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(x.doX);
            t.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** This page explains my problem better than I can: http://mikehadlow.blogspot.it/2012/11/using-blockingcollection-to-communicate.html

> Consider these (somewhat) common programming challenges:
>
> I’m using a third party library that is not thread safe, but I want my
>   application to share work between multiple threads. How do I marshal
>   calls between my multi-threaded code to the single threaded library? I
>   have a single source of events on a single thread, but I want to share
>   the work between a pool of multiple threads? I have multiple threads
>   emitting events, but I want to consume them on a single thread? One
>   way of doing this would be to have some shared state, a field or a
>   property on a static class, and wrap locks around it so that multiple
>   threads can access it safely. This is a pretty common way of trying to
>   skin this particular cat, but it’s shot through with traps for the
>   unwary. Also, it can hurt performance because access to the shared
>   resource is serialized, even though the things accessing it are
>   running in parallel.
>
> A better way is to use a BlockingCollection and have your threads
>   communicate via message classes.

Here's a working solution based on that website suggestion of using BlockingCollection:

```
namespace ThreadApp
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            int managedThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Main ManagedThreadId = " + managedThreadId);

            X x = new X();

            Y y = new Y();
            y.fun(x);

            x.doX();

        }
    }

    class X
    {
        private BlockingCollection<String> queue = new BlockingCollection<String>();

        public void Produce(String item)
        {
            queue.Add(item);
        }

        public void doX()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                String item = queue.Take();
                int managedThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("X ManagedThreadId = " + managedThreadId + " randomid=" + item);
                // Add your code to process the item here.
                // Do not start another task or thread. 
            }
        }
    }

    class Y
    {
        X x;

        public void fun(X x)
        {
            this.x = x;
            Thread t = new Thread(threadBody);
            t.Start();
        }

        void threadBody()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int managedThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

                Random rand = new Random();
                int randInt = rand.Next(1, 90);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Y ManagedThreadId = " + managedThreadId + " random-int" + randInt);
                x.Produce("random-int" + randInt);
                Thread.Sleep(randInt * 10);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above solution works, here's the output:

```
Main ManagedThreadId = 1
Y ManagedThreadId = 3 random-int24
X ManagedThreadId = 1 randomid=random-int24
Y ManagedThreadId = 3 random-int46
X ManagedThreadId = 1 randomid=random-int46
Y ManagedThreadId = 3 random-int48
X ManagedThreadId = 1 randomid=random-int48
```

The Y thread inserts a random-int and the X thread receives it in the queue and executes its method in the same thread as the Main thread.

However the problem is the doX() method is inside a while loop so it is blocking. If I have an X class which has some other functions to do and cannot block looping inside a method this approach would not work...

Comment: Do you need to preserve a thread or you just want to ensure that no 2 threads call the method simultaneously?

Comment: In the SSCC above only one managedThreadId should be printed even if two threads are invoking the method doX().  I want Y to let doX() method run as if it were called from the X main thread. Synchronizing the calls of the method is not the point

Comment: Your second thread will not execute code in the first thread.  However, it can signal the first thread so that code can run in the first thread.  In Windows apps we signal with Messages.  In an app like this you would use an EventWaitHandle or its subclasses AutoResetEvent or ManualResetEvent.  Your first thread waits on the event to be signaled.  Your second thread would Set() the event, signaling the first thread to run some code.  Pass the event to your second thread so it can call Set.  Wait for a signal in your first thread with event.WaitOne(). Let me know if you need example code.

Comment: Using EventSignals wouldn't fit a lot with my real world class X which is a standalone class with its logic. Making it receive Messages which trigger its own doX() method would be much better. However I see no Messaging example around.

Comment: If you give me more specifics on what you're trying to accomplish maybe I can put together an example.

Comment: I added more specifics in the question...

Comment: What do you mean by "behaves weirdly"?

Comment: it behaves as a non thread-safe class used by multiple threads: "weirdly", in my specific case it's a class connecting to a remote service and when called from another thread it disconnects all connections.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an awesome approach. Use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (Rx).

Rx primarily provides an observable/observer model that is extremely powerful, but it also provides a set of schedulers that can be used to simply work with threads. The `EventLoopScheduler` scheduler can be used to ensure that code runs on a single thread.

Try this example:

```
var els = new System.Reactive.Concurrency.EventLoopScheduler();

Console.WriteLine("A" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

els.Schedule(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("B" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
});

var thread = new Thread((ThreadStart)(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("C" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    els.Schedule(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("D" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    });
}));

thread.Start();
```

It outputs:

```
A12
B14
C16
D14
```

Both `"B"` and `"D"` run on the same thread even though the call to schedule an action came from two different threads.

You can use an `EventLoopScheduler` to make sure you code on `X` runs on the same thread.

Just NuGet "System.Reactive" to get the bits.